# Oracle query performance issue : Alternative for OR condition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

alternative for OR condition in Java

I have a query in which OR condition is giving performance Issue.

```
With T10 As(Select Query....)
select columns from T10 where 
( ( STATUS = 'Breach' and ALERT_TYP = 'FEED_BREACH')
  OR
( STATUS = 'Warning' and ALERT_TYP = 'FEED_WARN' ))
```

AND OTHER CONDITIONS................

When I execute Above query with no OR clause in either way...It Gives result in 20 secs.
If I execute it with OR clause...it keeps on running.
So I am looking for an alternative for the above .

Already tried

```
( STATUS, ALERT_TYP) in (('Breach','FEED_BREACH')),('Warning','FEED_WARN'))
```

Comment: Is there an index on `( STATUS, ALERT_TYP)` ?

Comment: yes Index is already applied on the columns.

Comment: could you run an Explain plan and post it?